# DB2 will only accept SRID's: 0, 1 and 4326?

Tags: coordinate-system, srid, db2

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here or just not understanding how this works but I cannot get DB2 to accept any coordinates that aren't either in SRID's 0, 1 or 4326. I'm trying to add data to a table with an SRID 2874 so I had the following code:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) 
VALUES 
(db2gse.ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)', 2874))
```

However, this results in:

```
SQL Error [38SU1]: Routine "GSEGEOMFROMWKT" (specific name "GSEGEOMWKT1") has returned an error SQLSTATE with diagnostic text "GSE3001N
Invalid SRS identifier "2874".".. SQLCODE=-443, SQLSTATE=38SU1, DRIVER=4.31.10
```

The same code with 4326, 0 or 1 works fine. But I cannot seem to get any single other SRID to work. Every one I've tried comes back with Invalid SRS identifier...

All the codes I'm trying are in ST_COORDINATE_SYSTEMS. Maybe I'm not getting something fundamental to this?

Comment: I know nothing about DB2... However, spatial reference is usually set at the feature class (table) level, not feature (record). Is your geometry column set to 4326? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2woc?topic=columns-registering-spatial

Comment: The syntax follows the documentation https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=parameters-st-srsid-st-srid. But by https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=parameters-st-geomfromtext the SRID should be in `DB2GSE.ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS` so it seems that you have searched the codes from a wrong table.

Comment: Yeah, that's odd. I wonder why there's a restriction on one and not the other. The ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS view only has 8 SRID's vs 100's for the other call.

Comment: Yeah this is the answer, for some reason you have to go with ```(db2gse.ST_SRID(db2gse.ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)'), 2874))```

Comment: This doesn't really work either, no matter how you set it up your original coordinates need to be in something that ST_GeomFromText will accept, or it won't work. Realize this is another question so will frame it that way. Your answer on ST_GeomFromText is the right one.